# how to redirect the output file of a bash script to a desired folder

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Hello I'm running this bash script here and the command "bwa index .." will generate several files, and this command doesn't have the "-o" flag for specifying output path. I want to redirect these files into a new folder. I've searched online and all the answers I came across are redirecting files generated to a specific file name, but how to generally just redirect the output files into a new folder? Thanks very much!

```
#!/bin/bash

### qsub file.name to run from anywhere
### first step of BMW, making indexed fasta file

#PBS -N bwa_index
#PBS -S /bin/bash
#PBS -l walltime=24:00:00
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=8
#PBS -l mem=64gb
#PBS -o /gpfs/data/mcnerney-lab/liuweihan/chip_seq/becker_lab/bwa_index.out
#PBS -e /gpfs/data/mcnerney-lab/liuweihan/chip_seq/becker_lab/bwa_index.err

date

module load gcc/6.2.0
module load bwa/0.7.17

bwa index -p mm10_bwa_idx -a bwtsw /gpfs/data/mcnerney-lab/liuweihan/chip_seq/becker_lab/mm10.fa

date
echo END
```

Comment: cd directory && bwa

Answer (score 0):

You can change to the target directory and then run the bwa command. Using [pushd and popd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushd_and_popd) will ensure that rest of the script runs in correct directory.

```
pushd some_directory
bwa index -p mm10_bwa_idx -a bwtsw /gpfs/data/mcnerney-lab/liuweihan/chip_seq/becker_lab/mm10.fa
popd
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**
You can define a *variable* and use it in your script.

**Second**
You can pass arguments to your script and capture them via `$1`, `$2`, `$3` and so on.

**Third** if you wanted to be fully dynamic by using option ( e.g. `--output` | `-o` ) you can use a simple parse as bellow:

```
#!/bin/bash

################################################################################
# main flags, both longs and shorts
################################################################################
ARGS=`getopt -o "o::" -l "output:" -- "$@"`
eval set -- "$ARGS"


declare -A _output;
_output['flag']=0;
_output['path']=0;

################################################################################
# extract options and their arguments into variables.
################################################################################
while true ; do
    case "$1" in
        -o | --output )
            _output['flag']=1;
            _output['path']=$2;
            shift 2;
        ;;
         --)
            shift;
            break;
         ;;

         * )
            echo "Internal error!" ; exit 1
         ;;
    esac
done

echo "output: ${_output['path']}";
```

And usage is super simple, you can use `--output <YOUR-PATH>` or `-o <YOUR-PATH>`

```
# test
./cli.sh --output /path/to/dir
output: /path/to/dir
./cli.sh -o /path/to/dir
output: /path/to/dir
```